# Vue v-bind with single curly braces expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bind

I'm just studying and experimenting with Vue.js.

By following this tutorial I came across a situation where a class needs to be added to a span element on a condition of the current element within a v-for loop and for that an expression with single curly braces was used as shown below:

```
 <p v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo">
    <span :class="{'is-completed' : todo.completed}">{{ todo.title }}</span>
 </p>
```

`todo.completed` is a boolean

Can anyone please explain to me what's going on with that `{'is-completed' : todo.completed}`?

Isn't that the syntax for objects in JavaScript? Why and how does that work for the v-bind directive?

Thank you!

Comment: For these kind of basic questions i would sugest reading through vues documentation. It will give you a deeper understanding than asking questions here. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: The single curly brace pair means that this is a JavaScript object

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's just a shorthand that is equivalent to a computed prop returning this object where each prop indicates a class name.

```html
<span :class="spanClasses">{{ todo.title }}</span>
```

```js
computed: {
  spanClasses () {
   return {
     'is-completed' : this.todo.completed
   }
  }
}
```